# Find if the value increased or decreased last time it changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm dragging an element up and down, I want it to do specific things depending on its attribute change. I need to know whether the value of its 'top' attribute increased or decreased since the last time it changed. How to do it?

```
header.draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: [0, 0, 0, '800px'],
    stop: function () {
        if (header.css('top') > '200px' && header.css('top') != 'auto') {
            header.animate({
                top: '800px'
            }, 1000);
            $('.nav').addClass('nav--active');
            $('.nav__wrapper').addClass('nav__wrapper--active');
            $('.nav__item').addClass('nav__item--active');
            $('.header__wrapper').addClass('header__wrapper--active');
        } else {
            header.animate({
                top: '0px'
            }, 500);
            $('.nav').removeClass('nav--active');
            $('.nav__wrapper').removeClass('nav__wrapper--active');
            $('.nav__item').removeClass('nav__item--active');
            $('.header__wrapper').removeClass('header__wrapper--active');
        }
    },
});
```

I'm using jQuery UI Draggable for dragging header, I want it to go top if I dragged it upward and similarly to set top = 800px if I dragged it downward.

Comment: please post your code with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use two variables `yStart` and `yStop` to store the `ui.offset.top` on daggable `start:` and draggable `stop:` events

```js
$("#dragHandle").draggable({
  axis: "y",
  containment: "parent",
  start: function(ev, ui) {
    this.yStart = ui.offset.top;
  },
  stop: function(ev, ui) {
    this.yStop = ui.offset.top;
    
    var px = this.yStop - this.yStart;
    if (px === 0) {
      console.log("Not moved");
    } else if (px > 0) {
      console.log("Moved Down by " + Math.abs(px) + "px");
    } else {
      console.log("Moved Up by " + Math.abs(px) + "px");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#dragWrapper {
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
}

#dragHandle {
  background: chocolate;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dragWrapper">
  <div id="dragHandle"></div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add an attribute to the element, for exemple 
    `<div number="0"> </div>`, and every time you drag it you change that number `<div number="2">`, then you compare it to the last number to see if is bigger or smaller. (you compare before changing)